# Bernoulli-like trial to obtain a given number of successes with high probabilty

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I have a set of independent Bernoulli trials $X_i$ (biased coins with probability $p$). How many coins do I need to throw to obtain at least $c$ successes with a-priori probability at least $\delta$?

Formally, I want $\mathbb{P}[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \geq c] \geq \delta$ which is the Binomial tail distribution, however $n$ is the variable. I am looking for something that I can reasonably solve for $n$. All the expressions I found, including typical Chernoff / Hoeffding bounds, are quite impractical for this direction. I'm fine with a $O(....)$ estimation, maybe this allows for a lot of simplifications.

I also found that this is closely related to the negative binomial distribution, however I didn't find any estimations for its CDF either.

EDIT, to clarify: My main goal is to show that the $n$ is (at most) polynomial (or maybe it is exponential?) in the given constants. I want to prove the time complexity of an sampling-based algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of at least $c$ successes in $n$ trials with probability $p$ of success in each can be expressed using a hypergeometric function
$$ G(c,n,p) = {n\choose c}{p}^{c} \left( 1-p \right) ^{n-c}
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}\left(1,c-n;\,c+1;\,{\frac {p}{p-1}}\right)}
$$
In principle $G(c,n,p)=\delta$ can be solved for $n$ numerically.

Asymptotically, as $n$ and $c$ get large (with $p$ and $\delta$ fixed) we may use the de Moivre-Laplace theorem.  A binomial($n,p$) random variable $X$
can be approximated by a normal random variable with the same mean $np$ and variance $np(1-p)$.  If $\Phi$ is the CDF of the standard normal random variable,
$$ \mathbb P(X \ge c) \approx 1 - \Phi\left( \frac{c-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\right)$$
This is $\delta$ if $$\frac{c-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \approx \Phi^{-1}(1-\delta) $$
i.e.
$$ n \approx \frac{c}{p}  - \frac{r}{2p} \sqrt{ (1-p)^2 r^2 + 4 c (1-p)} + \frac{(1-p) r^2}{2p}$$
where $r = \Phi^{-1}(1-\delta)$.

Comment: Thanks! That seems like a good start. I forgot that Binomial is approximated by Gaussian (especially considering that my $c$ is $\gg 10^{10}$). Lets see if I can make this into an explicit $O(...)$ estimate. The Gaussian inverse CDF should be reasonable to approximate I think.

EDIT: Added my overall proof goal to the question.